# Dual boot windows and linux

Tags: linux, linux-mint, windows, dual-boot

I have Windows 7 installed, and I have just installed Linux Mint 17. The PC automatically boots into Linux now. How can I get a dual boot startup screen with Windows 7 and Linux?

Are there any UI based applications for Linux that will configure this for me?

Comment: I don't know Mint, but usually if everything was set up correctly, Mint should at least have detected Windows during the installation and created an entry in the GRUB boot menu. It's possible that Mint hides the menu by default, though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows boot option is missing after installing CentOS 7, how can I get it back?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169787/windows-boot-option-is-missing-after-installing-centos-7-how-can-i-get-it-back)

Answer (score 1):

In order to dual boot windows and linux you must install Windows first. Its something about Windows not wanting to play nice with other OS's, I don't exactly know why. Once you have Windows 7 installed try installing linux normally, but when you get to partitions you will want to designate a section of your hard drive to Linux only. There are plenty of tutorials on YouTube, like this one: http://youtu.be/Q42pylkQvPc